# DB2: Need to extract string to the left of delimitere

Tags: db2

I have a column that looks like this:

```
SBN:123456=1
SBN:1234=0
SBN:12345678=5
```

I need to extract everything left of the equal sign ('=') for every row.  I attempted using SUBSTRING this way:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, SUBSTR(COLUMN2,1,LOCATE('=', COLUMN2)-1) AS STUFF FROM TABLE1;
```

Instead of extracting the text from the string, it gave me the error "The statement was not executed because a numeric argument of a scalar function is out of range." and I can't seem to figure out why.  What am I doing wrong?

I'm using DB2 11.1.4.4 on AIX, just FYI.

Comment: Your query works fine here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=a7b634c23e092d114b3152f54fef93f6

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.   There were some NULLs in the column that the query didn't like apparently.  Got rid of those and it worked fine.